# Forward inside tomcat webapp: sessions are not expired

Tags: java, tomcat, forward

I have a webservice that does quite simple a forward to another webapp located on the same Tomcat container.

```
private Response forward(
        @Context ServletContext context,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @Context HttpServletResponse response){
    ServletContext ctx = context.getContext("/myothewebapp");   
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher=ctx.getRequestDispatcher("/test");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    return Response.ok("").build();
}
```

This works as desired except the fact, that the sessions of this webapp are not being expired. In the tomcat manager you can see, that the opened sessions get accumulated quite fast, up to several hundreds of them.

I am not sure why they last when the response is already sent.
Any ideas what is missing in my forward-method?

Comment: Your forwarding the request not invalidating the session...The session won't expire unless you 1. Close the browser 2. Manually expire the session 3. Wait for the session timeout if set.

Comment: `session.invalidate();` can be used to invalidate the session...`session = request.getSession(true);` can be used to get a new session

Comment: Ok but then how does it come that sessions do not accumulate if I terminate the request just with usual return Response.ok().build();?

Comment: Each time you forward to another application a new session is created it doesn't share the session between applications...

Comment: When you just return you are still in the same application so there is no new session created...

Comment: why are you worried about accumulating sessions? You should be fine just make sure you have set a session timeout so they will automatically expire after no activity for a certain amount of time.

Comment: ok I supposed that it might decrease application performance if there are too many of them as it will e.g. be with database connections.

Comment: it all depends on you server the underlying hardware and the applications themselves...You should be fine though usually you don't need to worry about the amount of sessions. If it becomes an issue then you can revisit your architecture and see if you should make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

> Why they last when the response is already sent.

Why you think that session will be invalidated after response will be sent.

It will only be invalidated if session timeout occurs or you forcefully invalidate the session using :

```
Session#invalidate() method
```

Comment: Because it never happened to me that webapp sessions accumulate if I terminate the request just with usual return Response.ok().build();

Comment: **Why it will accumulate ?**, if you just return you are still in the same application and no new session going to be get created for it !